# Why is the return value of the fun function 8 instead of 7?

Tags: c, return-value, comma-operator

With reference to [Comma-Separated return arguments in C function [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32094189/comma-separated-return-arguments-in-c-function)
,

```
x=x+2,x+1;
```

will be evaluated as

```
x=x+2;
```

However, in case of the following code

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int fun(int x)
{
    return (x=x+2,x+1); //[A]
}

int main()
{
   int x=5;
   x=fun(x);
   printf("%d",x); // Output is 8
}
```

Shouldn't line [A],be evaluated as

```
x=x+2;
```

giving `x = 7`

Comment: Command flow goes from left to right in this case, you can also try `while(x=2,x<3)` to verify this - it will be an infinite loop.

Comment: Thank you for demonstrating why we try to avoid the comma operator.

Comment: @Observer: Well I guess we can put the test in the middle of a few more loop forms than I though.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The statement `return (x = x + 2, x + 1);` is equivalent to:

```c
x = x + 2; // x == 7
return x + 1; // returns 8
```

Comment: +1. And to directly address the OP's confusion: the statement `x = x + 2, x + 1;` is equivalent to the pair of statements `x = x + 2; x + 1;`. It's just that the statement `x + 1;` doesn't actually *do* anything, so we can just ignore that statement and say that it's equivalent to `x = x + 2;`. When you add a `return`, obviously the statement `return x + 1;` is no longer a no-op, so we can't ignore it anymore. :-)

Answer (score 15):

When writing `return (x=x+2,x+1)`, the first expression is evaluated first so `x=x+2` is evaluated, causing x to equal 7 as a side effect. Then the second expression is evaluated and returned, hence the function returns x+1 hence returns 8.

If you had written `return (x+2,x+1);`, the result would have been 6 because the first expression `x+2` doesn't have any side effect.

Comment: why ```return (x=x+2,x+1)``` causes a side effect?

Comment: @AshishKumar because it changes the value of `x`. Not really a "side effect" because it's still explicit, but it causes `x` to be different on the right side of the comma.

Comment: @AshishKumar The comma operator explicitly has a sequence point between the evaluation of the left and right operand. You are guaranteed that `x=x+2` is evaluated before `x+1`. Regardless, don't write crappy code like that and avoid `,` operator in general.

Answer (score 12):

Both parts in the `return` are evaluated respectively and the result of the last instruction is returned:

At first we have:

```
x = x + 2 // 7
```

Now `x` is updated to `7` before the second evaluation which gives:

```
x + 1 // 7 + 1 = 8
```

and finally return `8`.

For better understanding consider the case of intermediate variable as follows:

```
return (y = x + 2, y + 1);
```

Comment: is this a side effect of return, because that is not the standard behaviour for 
 the comma operator?

Comment: If you didn't assign the first expression to `x` then only the last expression will be taken into account as a return value

Comment: Try it with two variables, it could give you better idea as follows: `return (y = x + 2, y + 1)`

Comment: Now it makes sense.

Comment: nitpick: it's the comma operator that evaluates both parts and returns the latter. It's not specific to the `return` statement, you'd get the same effect with `y=(x=x+2, x+1)`

Comment: @ilkkachu, I agree but I was talking about that specific cass

Answer (score 6):

The QA you conveniently linked states

> The comma operator evaluates a series of expressions. The value of the
>   comma group is the value of the last element in the list.

so the value of

```
x+2,x+1;
```

is `x+1` and there are no side effects.

---

Sample code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char * argv){
    int x;
    x = 0;
    x = (x+2, x+1);
    printf("%d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

results in `1` when run.

---

However, when you do

```
return (x=x+2, x+1)
```

you *do have a side effect*: `x` is incremented by two first, then `x` is incremented by 1 and the result is returned.

Comment: according to that logic, x should be 6, not 8.

Comment: Oh, you're right

Comment: see my edit. is it clear to you why?

Comment: is the side effect caused due to the return statement?

Comment: No. The side effect would happen also if you said `int y = (x=x+2, x+1)`. The side effect is that the value of `x+2` is assigned to `x` (in a first step, and later `x+1` is computed)

Comment: The difference lies between `(x+2, x+1)` and `(x=x+2, x+1)`

Comment: @lucidbrot is correct. x+1 does not increment the variable x at all, it increments the value of x.   x+1 is returned with x unmodified.

Answer (score 3):

As other users stated, the command flow goes from left to right, and in the case of `return`, it will give back the value in the rightmost operator. What is written before this operator and separated by commas is no different from line written expressions. Example:

```
return (x = x + 2, x = x - 5, x + 1);
```

The code below produces the same result:

```
x = x + 2;  
x = x - 5;
return x + 1;
```

For `x = 0`, this would return `-2`. Notice that, for both codes, if we change `x = x - 5` to `x - 5`, i.e, we are subtracting `5` from `x` but not saving its result anywhere, the return value of `x` will change to `3` and, therefore, confirming the equivalency.

Answer (score 3):

That's a matter of operator precedence.

`x=x+2,x+1` is evaluated as `(x=x+2), (x+1)` and not as `x=(x+2,x+1)`

Answer (score 0):

The comma operator introduces a sequence point in your code. The statements are evaluated in this order:

1. `x = x + 2`, at which point the local `x` in `fun` is 7.
2. `x + 1`, which evaluates to 8, and is returned.

To clarify, here's a parenthesized version showing operator precedence:

```
return (x=x+2),x+1;
```

The left-hand expression is evaluated and its value is thrown away. The right-hand expression's value is what is returned.